# Passing around Connection

Tags: java, exception-handling

I have a `myCon=getUnusedConnection()` method that gets a connection from `Connection` pool. I also have a `releaseConnection(myCon)` method to release `Connection` to the pool after finishing using it.

When coding, I need to select data from the database many times.  I also want to reuse my code.  I want to have many methods for a single action.

Example:

```
public static List<String[]> getData(){
    Connection myCon=null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt=null;
    try{
        myCon=getUnusedConnection();
        String sql="select ........";
        preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
        String str="";
        if(results.next()){
             str=results.getString(1);
        }
        if(!str.equals("")){
             List<String[]> list=getData2(myCon, preparedStmt, str);
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                              ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
    }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
    }
    finally{
        releaseConnection (myCon);
        closeStatement (preparedStmt);
    }
    return null;
}

public static List<String[]> getData2(Connection myCon, PreparedStatement preparedStmt, String str){

     try{
         List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
         String sql="c.......";
         preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
         while(results.next()){
             list.add(results.getString(1));
         }
         return list;
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                              ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
    }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
    }
    finally {

        closeStatement(preparedStmt);
        releaseConnection(myCon); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do I need to include `try - catch - finally` in `getData2`, since I am passing `myCon` and `prepareStatement` around?  I am not sure if this the right way to code.

Is the way I'm coding considered standard?  If not, do you have something better in mind?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077817/java-se/understanding-jpa--part-1--the-object-oriented-paradigm-of-data-persistence.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code. Let's go through the more important ones:

- you should close the PreparedStatement **before** you return the connection to the pool.... should be:

  ```
  finally{
      closeStatement (preparedStmt);
      releaseConnection (myCon);
  }
  ```
- you should be closing the ResultSet in addition to the Statement!
- but, this is all somewhat pointless because you only use your prepared statement once.... A prepared statement is useful for two reasons only:

  1. they separate issues in syntax from issues in data (you get syntax errors early) ... but, your SQL Query code will not have syntax errors... right?
  2. they improve performance **IF THEY ARE REUSED**, but you are not reusing them.
- If you are using Java 7 you should be using [try-with-resources logic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your objects. This will remove the need for the finally block.

JDBC Connection pools are relatively complicated 'animals'. I strongly recommend you leverage the functionality that others have built. For example, Tomcat, WebSphere and I am sure other applications servers have good connection-pooling processes. Additionally, stand-alone applications can (re)use things like [the Apache DBCP component](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/index.html) (which also [supports PreparedStatement connection pools](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html))